# How to forward a value received in a websocket to another websocket?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I need to send commands to a raspberry from a smartphone through a Virtual Private Server.
I'm trying to use Node.js to accomplish this.

I can send messages/requests from the smartphone and from the raspberry (clients) to the server but i can not forward messages received from the android app to the raspberry. 
Commands sent from the mobile app are so stored:

`var jsonObject = querystring.parse(fullBody);`

This is the entire script:

```
var http = require("http")
, fs = require('fs')
, ursa = require('ursa')
, url = require('url')
, querystring = require('querystring')
, net = require('net')
, io = require('socket.io').listen(80)
, crt
, key
, msg
, id
;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'synchronized' });

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
     var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

     switch(path){
        case '/inst':
             var req = request;

              if (req.method == 'POST') {
                     console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
                     var fullBody = '';
                     req.on('data', function(chunk) {

                           // append the current chunk of data to the fullBody variable
                           fullBody += chunk.toString();
                     });
                     req.on('end', function() {
                             // parse the received body data
                             var jsonObject = querystring.parse(fullBody);

                             msg = key.decrypt(jsonObject.cr, 'base64', 'utf8');
                             console.log(msg);
                    if(msg){
                          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                          response.write('all ok ');
                           }
                     });
             }

            break;
        case '/app':   //Commands received from android "app"
              var req = request;

              if (req.method == 'POST') {
                     console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
                     var fullBody = '';
                     req.on('data', function(chunk) {

                       // append the current chunk of data to the fullBody variable
                       fullBody += chunk.toString();
                     });
                     req.on('end', function() {
                         // parse the received body data
                         var jsonObject = querystring.parse(fullBody);
                         console.log(fullBody);
                         //TODO remove all console.log
                         console.log(jsonObject.food);
                  });
             }
        break;

        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
       }
        response.end();
    });
    server.listen(8002);

    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a little confused on how sockets works.

In my script above i simply added an "emit" event into "/app" switch case:

```
case '/app':   //Commands received from android "app"
      var req = request;

      if (req.method == 'POST') {
           console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
           var fullBody = '';
           req.on('data', function(chunk) {
               // append the current chunk of data to the fullBody variable
               fullBody += chunk.toString();
               });
           req.on('end', function() {
              // parse the received body data
               var jsonObject = querystring.parse(fullBody);

               //****Added emit socket event****
               socket.emit('message', {'message':jsonObject });

               });
         }
break;
```